# Moving recursively in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Does anybody know how to move "on the ones" and change them to 2? I think we need recursion, but I'm not very good at it, so I'm asking you for help.

You can only move up, down, left or right.

Here is an example:

```
int[][] a = {{ 0, 0, 0},
             {1, 1, 0},
             {1, 1, 1},
             {1, 0, 1} };

recursiveFunction(a, 1, 1); // (<array you're checking>, <x of the group>, <y of the group>

/* int a now contains:
 * { 0, 0, 0,
 *   2, 2, 0,
 *   2, 2, 2,
 *   2, 0, 2 } */

int[][] b = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
             {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
             {1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
             {1, 0, 1, 0, 1} };

recursiveFunction(b, 0, 5);
/* int b now contains:
 * { 0, 0, 0, 0, 2
 *   1, 1, 0, 0, 2
 *   1, 1, 1, 0, 2
 *   1, 0, 1, 0, 2 } */
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. You declare a 2d array, but initialize it as a 1d array.

Comment: besides the type should not be char but int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you want to change value of the connected component you start out in this should work.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] b = 
            {
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}
            };

        rec(b, 0, 4);

        for (int[] row : b) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }

    public static void rec(final int[][] grid, final int row, final int col) {
        if (grid[row][col] != 1) return;

        grid[row][col]++;

        if (row-1 >= 0) rec(grid, row-1, col);
        if (row+1 < grid.length) rec(grid, row+1, col);
        if (col-1 >= 0) rec(grid, row, col-1);
        if (col+1 < grid[0].length) rec(grid, row, col+1);
    }
}
```

Note that depending of how big your components are you might run out of stack. Either you'd then have to manage your own stack explicitly in the code or you would need to increase the stack space available to the JVM.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand this. But I think it also changes the values diagonal of the element we're looking at. It should only change the values left, right, up or down

Comment: Ok, simplified it. Now it won't traverse diagonally.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need recursion for this .It is pretty straightforward.Also notice the way I have created a 2d array

```
char[][] a = { {0, 0, 0},
           {1, 1, 0},
           {1, 1, 1},
           {1, 0, 1 }}; 

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {

     if(a[i][j] == 1)
        a[i][j] = 2;
   }

  }
```

Would this work ?

Comment: Srry I wasn't too clear in the post.
This would work for this simple case, but what I get is a much larger array with multiple groups and I must only change the one I'm told.
A group is all the ones connected left, right, up or down.

Comment: We have to use the connected components algorithm to do it in an optimal way.I have done this some time back so I am going through it and will edit my solution shortly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#Graphical_example_of_two-pass_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You have defined just 1D array and its number so you should use int.

Instead of doing it recursively, try solving it easily with two for loops (1 for row and 1 for column) for 2D array as below:

```
int array[][] = {{0, 0, 0},
                 {1, 1, 0},
                 {1, 1, 1},
                 {1, 0, 1}};
for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< array[0].length; j++) {
         if (array[i][j] == 1) {
             array[i][j] = 2;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologise to you too. The original post was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and pass it the value that you want to replace. It will be better then recursion because you can avoid extra cost of `stack` that will be required during each recursive call

```
public static void replace(char[][] arr, char target, char replacment) {
    for (int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j< arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == target) {
                arr[i][j] = replacment;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
replace(arr, (char)1, (char)2);
```

Comment: your answer is more general,1 vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need recursion? You could just iterate over the array and multiply every element by two (since `0 * 2` is `0` anyway, and it's faster than having to check the element):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; ++j) {
        a[i][j] *= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: but if he had values other than one and two, then this is wrong

Comment: @user2397162 true - but the question was about a matrix of ones and zeroes. As I stated, this is an optimization. If your data is different, you'd have to check the content of the elements - `if (a[i][j] == 1) {a[i][j] = 2;}`

Comment: Nice solution, but the original post was misleading. Sorry. I edited it now and it should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 the *Arrays.parallelSetAll* method could be used.

```
public static void replace(int[][] arr, int target, int replacement) {
    Arrays.parallelSetAll(arr, row -> {
        Arrays.parallelSetAll(arr[row], col -> arr[row][col] == target ? replacement : arr[row][col]);
        return arr[row];
    });
}
```

It uses the Java 8 Stream API:s and offers a quite nice compact programming model. Furthermore, it uses the *ForkJoinPool* so performance *could* be better since it may be multi-threaded (depending on the CPU etc).